# What is that spooky humming sound heard in earthquake footages?

Tags: earthquakes

In most of the earthquake footages filmed outside during the earthquake that hit Mexico City on September 9, 2017 there was a distinctive streak of hum in rapid succession that could be heard in the background. It sounded like someone is constantly hitting the tuning forks onto a light tower like 2 times per second.

You can find [numerous footages on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mexico%20city%20earthquake%20footage), but I picked one and fetched the audio portion covering the hums, you can listen to the audio [at this link here](https://soundcloud.com/fahadash-1/sound-of-earthquake-in-mexico-9192017) (sorry I did not know how to upload an audio to SE).

Here is the waveform of the sound

[image: Mexico City Earthquake Waveform]

What is that sound? What is causing this sound? If this was buildings or surrounding objects, why is there a pattern? Why is this sound heard in every footage no matter where they are filmed as long as they were filmed outside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wailing sirens.

Examples [1](https://youtu.be/Z_bueA1XQqg?t=2m33s), [2](https://youtu.be/yAun0cs_cGc?t=28s) where you see people come running out, i.e. exactly when you'd expect sirens, or [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86QMhxHd404), or [4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RxFFX_f1II) and [5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGanqZJ-Pz8) where they are explicitly mentioned.